# Unwanted characters added when using GSON to convert from object to String

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I'm using Google Gson to convert an array of object into an array of String. Here is my code:

TestFile.java

```
public class TestFile {
 public String[] StringtoJSon(Object[] obj) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String[] converted = new String[obj.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        converted[i] = gson.toJson(obj[i]);
    }
    return converted;
 }
}
```

main.java

```
 TestFile tf = new TestFile();    
 Object[] obj = {"tt",1, "yyom"};
 String[] convObj = tf.StringtoJSon(obj);
 generateJSONFile(convObj);// this is class that generate a file in JSON format
```

so in the file generated I found that "\\" was added to each string element from the array

example:

```
"sparse" : false,
        "weight" : 1.0,
        "values" : [
            "'\\\"tt\\\"'",
            "4",   /*the length of the first element "tt"*/
            "1",
            "1",     /*the length of the second element 1 */
            "'\\\"yyom\\\"'",
            "6",     /*the length of the last element "yyom"*/

        ]
```

Since I need the exact length of each element from the array I need to delete the added characters, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you add the code inside generateJSONFile? I think it's better to fix it, then it's to delete unwanted symbols afterwards.

Comment: I'm using JSONSaver from Weka api to save the file in JSON format [link] (http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/JSONLoader.html) and I got the same result when I'm writing the file into ARFF file

Answer (score 3):

It seems, you pass an array of string wich are already JSON-ed to `generateJSONFile()`. And so they already consist quotations. Then `generateJSONFile` treats them as data strings and so escapes the quotations.

So you have JSON in JSON problem.

Comment: I'm using JSONSaver from Weka api to save the file in JSON format [link] (http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/JSONLoader.html) and I got the same result when I'm writing the file into ARFF file